# Enter to multiple directories, find files with specific extension and copy to a new directory

Tags: bash

I´m looking for some help to find out the solution for this command.
I want to enter multiple directories, all end with this *_genomic_prokka, then in these directories, there are files with a specific extension *.faa
Here is an example:

```
Directory:
GCA_927910925.1_ERR3827219_bin.1_metaWRAP_v1.1_MAG_genomic_prokka
```

Then,

```
File: 
GCA_916048385.1_ERR2764975_bin.4_metaWRAP_v1.1_MAG_genomic_prkk.faa
```

So, I think in a bash command to do that:

```
find ~/*_genomic_prokka ~/*.faa -exec cp *.faa > ~/selected_faa
```

"~/selected_faa" is the new directory with all the *.faa files found and copy into this new directory.
This command doesn´t work properly because finds the *_genomic_prokka but then doesn´t find *.faa
I think that I´m using the find command in a bad way, maybe there is another with to enter on every *_genomic_prokka directories and find all *.faa, to copy them on this new directory.
Any idea?

Comment: use can globs directly `cp ~/*_genomic_prokka/*.faa ~/selected_faa/`  (unless there are too much files)

Comment: There are 309 files, I going to use your command, I hope to work it!

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn´t work

Comment: What kind of error did you get? Does the directory `~/selected_faa/` exists?

Comment: `cp: accessing /... Not a directory` I don´t understand why, because the directory exist (selected_faa). I have all the *_genomic_prokka directories in the same folder that selected_faa

Comment: What is the output of the command `file ~/selected_faa`? if it isn't a directory then you'll have to delete it with `rm -f ~/selected_faa` then create the directory with `mkdir ~/selected_faa`

Comment: Thank for your help, however, the idea doesn´t work for me :(
I find the solution using a for loop!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a for loop to enter each directory, copy each .faa file and then return and copy to a new directory:

```
for f in *_genomic_prokka
do
        cd $f
        cp *.faa ../selected_faa
        cd ..
done
```